# what's meaning of the following linux script

Tags: bash, ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Why so many updates? What is meaning of `ppa:chris-lea`?

Comment: It's good that you ask before just running it. However, `man add-apt-repository` or googling `node.js chris lea` will tell you more than enough

Comment: Shouldn't this be on AskUbuntu?

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Updates the local package database with new information about packages that are available in the repositories. As [terdon pointed out](https://superuser.com/a/641979), this only needs to be done once (before installing packages).

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
```

Installs the packages `python-software-properties`, `python`, `g++`, and `make`, unless they are already installed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Adds Chris Lea's node.js repository and installs node.js from it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Adds webupd8team's java repository.

---

PPA stands for "Personal Package Archive". They contain unofficial packages contributed by anyone to [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net). **node.js** and **java** are available in the standard repositories though, so it would be better to install them from there unless you have a specific reason not to (like requiring features that are not available in the older packages from the official repositories.)

Answer (score 1):

Since Josh already explained, I just want to point out that that is a ridiculously round about way of doing things and causes may more `update`s to be run than necessary, Do this instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make nodejs
```